# AFHTTPSessionManager with multiple requests in rapid succession (AFNetworking 2.0)

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, afnetworking-2

i am new to iOS programming, still learning.

EDIT: !!!!!! Everything in my code works. My question is about the delegation pattern i use, 
if i am generating problems in the background that i have no idea of, or if there is a better way to handle my situation in AFNetworking...

I have created an API for my app by subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager.
My API creates a singleton and returns it and supplies public functions for various requests. And those functions create parameter lists, and make GET requests on the server like this:

```
- (void)getCharacterListForKeyID:(NSString *)keyID vCode:(NSString *)vCode sender:(id)delegate
{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    parameters[@"keyID"] = keyID;
    parameters[@"vCode"] = vCode;

    [self GET:@"account/Characters.xml.aspx" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        self.xmlWholeData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.errorDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
        [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
        XMLParser.delegate = self;
        [XMLParser parse];

        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(EVEAPIHTTPClient:didHTTPRequestWithResult:)]) {
            [delegate EVEAPIHTTPClient:self didHTTPRequestWithResult:self.xmlWholeData];
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(EVEAPIHTTPClient:didFailWithError:)]) {
            [delegate EVEAPIHTTPClient:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }];
}
```

I was using a normal protocol/delegate method earlier. But once i make calls this API more than once like this: (IT WAS LIKE THIS:)

```
EVEAPIHTTPClient *client = [EVEAPIHTTPClient sharedEVEAPIHTTPClient];
client.delegate = self;
[client getCharacterListForKeyID:self.keyID vCode:self.vCode];
```

Previous call's delegate was being overwritten by next. So i changed to above style. Passing sender as an argument in the function:

```
EVEAPIHTTPClient *client = [EVEAPIHTTPClient sharedEVEAPIHTTPClient];
[client getCharacterListForKeyID:self.keyID vCode:self.vCode sender:self];
```

And i pass this sender to GET request's success and failure blocks.

What i wonder is : "Is this a good programming practice ?". Passing objects to blocks like this should be avoided if possible ? Is there any other more elegant way in AFHTTPSessionManager to handle this type of work (making same GET request over and over with different parameters and returning results to the respective request owners) more elegantly ?

Comment: You're on the wrong way, the question you should ask yourself is: Is it really necessary to use a SAX parser (NSXMLParser is a SAX parser) in this case? I suggest you to use one of the several available DOM parser or, rather, as an exercise, you could wrap NSXMLParser to get a DOM parser

Comment: You should look at [AFURLResponseSerialization](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h) and implement your own serializer so that you receive the required object in the success parameter rather than raw response body text. The built-in [AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h#L154) may be suitable for your needs.

Comment: I don't have a problem with parsing or anything HepaKKes, everything in my code works. My question is about delegation pattern that i use : if i should avoid using the way i used because of retain cycles or other big promlems i have no idea about..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegation pattern falters when it comes to simplicity and asynchronous request processing. You should be using blocks, here's an example

Your server class:

```
static NSString *const kNews = @"user_news/"; // somewhere above the @implementation

- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)newsWithPage:(NSNumber *)page
                            lastNewsID:(NSNumber *)lastNewsID
                            completion:(void (^)(NSString *errMsg, NSArray *news, NSNumber *nextPage))completionBlock {
  return [self GET:kNews
        parameters:@{@"page" : page,
                     @"news_id" : lastNewsID
                     }
           success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
             NSArray *news = nil;
             NSNumber *nextPage = nil;
             NSString *errors = [self errors:responseObject[@"errors"]]; // process errors

             if ([responseObject[@"status"] boolValue]) {
               news = responseObject[@"news"];
               nextPage = responseObject[@"next_page"];
               [self assignToken];
             }

             completionBlock(errors, news, nextPage);
           }
           failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
             NSString *errors = [self errors:error];
             completionBlock(errors, nil, nil);
           }];
}
```

The caller

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [_task cancel]; // you don't want this task to execute if user suddenly removes your controller from the navigation controller's stack
}

- (void)requestNews {
  typeof(self) __weak wself = self; // to avoid the retain cycle
  self.task = [[GSGServer sharedInstance] newsWithPage:self.page
                                            lastNewsID:self.lastNewsID
                                            completion:^(NSString *errMsg, NSArray *news, NSNumber *nextPage) {
                                                 if (errMsg) {
                                                   [GSGAppDelegate alertQuick:errMsg]; // shortcut for posting UIAlertView, uses errMsg for message and "Error" as a title
                                                   return;
                                                 }
                                                 [wself.news addObjectsFromArray:news];
                                                 wself.lastNewsID = [wself.news firstObject][@"id"];
                                                 wself.page = nextPage;
                                                 [wself.tableView reloadData];
                                               }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess this is the elegant way i have been looking for all along.. I have another quick question: Lets say i do multiple GETs from same or different ViewControllers. I should create a task array and cancel all of them if they need to be canceled right at a dealloc situation?

Comment: Yeah, array should do. Most of the time you really want to retain the requests that should be cancelled by a user's action, like when user inputs a dynamic search query.

Comment: What about handling global errors? Wouldn't using delegation be easier since you can override a delegate method in a "base" view controller class?

Comment: @BassemSameh delegation is used for another purpose. You use delegates when you have a single object that handles a big volume of callbacks to its delegate, like `UITableView` does. Blocks are intended for a single operation scope. For instance you want to fetch a list of latest news like in this example or download user's profile information while an indicator is displaying "loading" status. Handling global errors shouldn't be tied to a view controller class I'd say, some networking operations are handled inside custom views or objects. You need to use a singleton for server communication

Comment: @Eugene Makes sense not to have errors tied to a view controller since it's not always making the requests. The thing is, I already have a "client" singleton, however, I wanted to separate the UI from the client/error handling logic. For instance, if I wanted to show a login modal or a generic alert, wouldn't it make sense to use a base view controller for that (especially since I have direct access to the current view)? I already opted for using notifications for handling global errors. Anyway, sorry for going off-topic and thanks for taking the time to explain the difference.